# How to replace nested childview with its nested childview?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Here is the JSBin http://jsbin.com/jebigi/1/.

I want to know how I can get the details view to replace the address view when the button address is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can totally do that

```
App.LocationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    address: function() {
      this.render('details');
    }
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/worojowepako/1/edit)